# convert document.write to getElementById / innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, document.write

Im writing a script that will have a quest randomly pop up when you refresh the page. Ive got the script working, but, the current one puts the texts at the top left-hand corner of the screen.

How do I convert what I already have to something like getElementById & innerHTML and place a span tag with an id="quest_id" inside the div I'd like the text to show up in?

Im a beginner at javascript, I know how to do most of these things by themselves, but integrating them together screws me up. Usually my problem is simple syntax I dont yet understand fully.

```
<script language="JavaScript">



var str = "click to go to the quest";
var quest = str.link("index.html");


var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "You found a quest! - " + quest;
r_text[1] = " ";
r_text[2] = " ";
r_text[3] = " ";
r_text[4] = " ";
r_text[5] = " ";
r_text[6] = " ";
r_text[7] = " ";
r_text[8] = " ";
r_text[9] = " ";

var i = Math.floor(10*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: no, javascript only. im not learning jquery yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, this should work, the 2nd script tag will load after the `<body>` and the `<div>` will be available.:

```
var str = "click to go to the quest";
var quest = str.link("index.html");


var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "You found a quest! - " + quest;
r_text[1] = "1 ";
r_text[2] = " 2";
r_text[3] = " 3";
r_text[4] = " 4";
r_text[5] = " 5";
r_text[6] = " 6";
r_text[7] = " 7";
r_text[8] = " 8";
r_text[9] = " 9";

var i = Math.floor(10*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);


//-->
</script>

<body>
    <div id="display">Here: </div>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=r_text[i];
</script>
```

Comment: Once I took the first document.write out, it worked perfectly! Thanks!